# Is it possible to specify the path to save files received via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to send and receive multiple files via Bluetooth in my Android app. My app runs in receiving device and sending device. Then, one of the devices starts to send files to another device.

Is it possible to specify the custom path to save files on receiving device? Please help.

Comment: When it is your app, of course. What is the problem? Just program it to do so.

Comment: 'Then, one of the devices starts to send files to another device. ' Devices? No. You said your apps were doing that.

Comment: One device send files and another device receive this files. If this work  is possible . Do you have an example code?

Comment: You did not read my comment. Devices will not send and receive. Only apps.  You told that you have already programmed such apps. And that they run. So what kind of code do you need?